# search and replace within multidimensional array using RecursiveIteratorIterator php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i am newbie in php and classes,

i have a multidimensional array which i want to loop and replace a portion of a string if it exists.

this is my array :

```
$unser = array(
    "a" => "https://technet.microsoft.com",
    "b" => "https://google.com",
    "c" => "https://microsoft.com",
    "d" => array(
              "a" => "https://microsoft.com",
              "b" => "https://bing.com",
              "c" => "https://office.com",
              "d" => "https://msn.com"
          );
);
```

the value that i want to search for is : **microsoft** and i want to replace it with **stackoverflow**, and save the array so that i can use it with other functions such as json_encode.

i was able to loop on the array and search for the item and replace it but it was not saving the array i don't know why.

```
<?php

$unser = array(
    "a" => "https://technet.microsoft.com",
    "b" => "https://google.com",
    "c" => "https://microsoft.com",
    "d" => array(
              "a" => "https://microsoft.com",
              "b" => "https://bing.com",
              "c" => "https://office.com",
              "d" => "https://msn.com"
          );
);

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($unser));
foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value,'microsoft') !== false) {
        #echo($value);
        $value = substr_replace('microsoft', 'stackoverflow', $value);
        #echo($value);
    }
}

var_dump(iterator_to_array($iterator,true)); 

?>
```

thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do it in way too complex manner. You can simply use the `str_replace()` function ([see documentation here for details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)) to do this.

**For Multi Dimensional Array:**

```
$data = array(); //Multi-D Array

foreach($data as $key => $subarray)
{
    foreach($subarray as $subkey => $subsubarray)
    {
        if (strpos($value, 'microsoft') !== false)
        {            
            $data[$key][$subkey] = str_replace('microsoft', 'stackoverflow', $value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**For One Dimensional Array:**

```
$data = array(
    "a" => "https://technet.microsoft.com",
    "b" => "https://google.com",
    "c" => "https://microsoft.com",
    "d" => "https://yahoo.com"
    );

foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    if (strpos($value, 'microsoft') !== false)
    {
        $data[$key] = str_replace('microsoft', 'stackoverflow', $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok it worked for one nested array with array . i have an array with 4 nested arrays inside.. how should i do it ?

Comment: You can always just add two more levels of `foreach` loop for it to work with 4 levels of array. I know it's not a pretty solution, but it works. Try that and tell me if it works. I'll try and look for a better solution myself.

Comment: i added 2 more foreach-s and added and an if (is_array) so incease it is not array ..

Comment: yes it did, but i don't know about all the arrays that i have so i will have to test it on all of them to see what the nesting count to add them all e.g. like 10 nested foreach-s just in case

Comment: I'll try and find a better solution during the day if I can. This has really got me very curious! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE: I see you updated your question so now my answer is not so relative.*

You can do this much easier. Here you go:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    "a" => "https://technet.microsoft.com",
    "b" => "https://google.com",
    "c" => "https://microsoft.com",
    "d" => "https://yahoo.com"
);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value, 'microsoft') !== false) {
        $data[$key] = str_replace('microsoft', 'stackoverflow', $value);

    }
}

var_dump($data);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(33) "https://technet.stackoverflow.com"
  ["b"]=>
  string(18) "https://google.com"
  ["c"]=>
  string(25) "https://stackoverflow.com"
  ["d"]=>
  string(17) "https://yahoo.com"
}
```

Comment: thanks , that worked for the simple array , but did not work for the multidimensional array it gave me this error message . Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in